# How to apply design guide for iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I asked a designer for an app though I'm new to iOS.
He gave me the design guide only for iPhone 6.

How to apply the design guide for other devices like iPhone 4S which has lower resolution and different ratio.

How would I apply the design guide?
I'm currently using auto-layout but I do not understand auto-layout totally.

Are there any references for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you are new then you must know how to detect which device you are using programmatically .
These are `macros` use these to detect

```
#define IS_IPAD         (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

#define IS_IPHONE       (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_4     (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5     (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6     (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
```

now you can use these for make any view like if you want to create button with width of screen size and height 100.

Then it is way to create button programmatically for any device

```
float screenWidth=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
float screenHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

UIButton *btnLock=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnLock.frame= CGRectMake(0, 50, screenWidth, 100);
btnLock.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:btnLock];
```

This is way if you want to coding programatically. Thanks

Comment: Do I have to apply the guide programatically? Sometimes I put views in xib.

Comment: no problem if you push xib, in xib too you can make any view programatically. This is one of approach sir.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to iOS. How would the padding be for different devices? For example, a button with 10 left-padding and 10 right-padding in iPhone 6. Should they be smaller in iPhone 4 and larger in iPhone 6 Plus? How about font size?

Answer (score 0):

```
float screenWidth=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
float screenHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

int padding = 10;
UIButton *btnLock=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnLock.frame= CGRectMake(padding, 50, screenWidth-padding*2, 100);
btnLock.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:btnLock];
```

this will give padding 10 to each iPhone . try it thanks

Comment: I asked if the padding size should be different for different devices.